# Is there a way to shorten this specific code snippet?

Tags: python

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    f1 = b - w
    f2 = a - w

    if f1 < 0:
        f1 = f1 * (-1)
    elif f2 < 0:
        f2 = f2 * (-1)
    else:
        pass

    return f1, f2
x = cross(10, 7, 5)
print(x)
```

I tried to make this more pythonic, e.g. shorten it and combine it with shorted one line if-conditions, though I couldn't find any way.. Does anyone know how to shorten it?

I want to make "both" the f1 and f2 positive if any of them is negative.

Comment: Use `return math.abs(b-w), math.abs(a-w)` as a one-liner solution

Comment: OP's code has an `elif`. If both `f1` and `f2` are negative, only `f1` is turned positive. ALL the answers so far has different behavior. Test with `cross(1,2,5)`.

Comment: @velotoy, what is it you're trying to shorten? You can remove the `else: pass`, but everything else seems ok. Also, is it your intention to only change the sign of `f1` if both `f1` and `f2` are negative?

Comment: @Aziz oh I didn't quite catch that! My intentions are to only get positive values, e.g. if either f1 or f2 are negative, output the positive. I also thought of turning it into a string and stripping the "-" to achieve it.. Any opinions?

Comment: The `elif` part in your code results in `f2` remaining negative if `f1` was positive too. But since you want both to be positive, @VisheshMangla's original answer is correct.

Comment: if you want you can use this type of comparison in python (false,true)[Decision Check]  ((-1,(b-c,c-a))[a<c], (c-b,a-c) )[b<c]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing pythonic here

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    f1 = b - w
    f2 = a - w

    f1 = f1 if f1>0 else -f1
    f2 = f2 if f2>0 else -f2
    
    return f1, f2

x = cross(10, 7, 5)

print(x)
```

But better will be just to return the abs value

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    return list(map(abs, ( b - w,  a - w)))
```

But if you were talking about if else like logic, well it can be reduced to one liner but it would be just more compact code but not efficient.

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    f1 = b - w
    f2 = a - w

 
    
    return abs(f1), abs(f2) if f1!= abs(f1) else f2 

x = cross(10, 7, 5)

print(x)
```

Comment: The behavior is different. If both `f1` and `f2` are negative, OP's code will only change `f1`. (I didn't downvote your answer, btw)

Comment: oh ok, if else trap

Comment: OP's intention was to get both positive anyway. So I rolled back your original answer, since it was correct :)

Comment: Wow, but how did you revert my answer? If I delete something I don't get the answer back.

Comment: hey but, w8 this removed my latest answer. That was more appropriate wrt to the code provided, leaving intentions apart.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this will handle the tricky if/else:

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    f1 = w-b if (b-w) < 0 else b-w
    f2 = w-a if ((a-w) < 0 and (b-w) >= 0) else a-w
    return f1, f2
x = cross(10, 7, 5)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    f1 = abs(b - w)
    f2 = abs(a - w)
    return f1, f2
print(f1,f2)

>>>cross(10,7,5)

>>>output = (2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

one-liner solution:

```
def cross(a, b, w):
    return (abs(b-w),a-w) if b-w<0 else (b-w, abs(a-w)) if a-w<0 else (b-w,a-w)

x = cross(1, 2, 5)
print(x)
```

output:

```
(3, -4)
```